# how to install cross compiled programs (thttpd) on arm linux boards

Tags: linux, service, arm, cross-compiling, thttpd

I cross complied thttpd with php for arm linux boards successfully and I got a single file namged thttpd. I copied this file to arm board and ran it successfully with the following command:

```
thttpd -C CONFIG_FILE // CONFIG_FILE is the path of thttpd configuration file.
```

the question is: How can I **INSTALL** the thttpd on the target (here the arm board) to it run automatically, for example as a service. You know when you compile thttpd on normal linux (x86) you can install it using "make install" command, but what can I do on the arm board with the single executable thttpd file?

Offcourse this is my general question that how can I install cross compiled programs on the arm boards?